# " multiple active partitions " ERROR

Tags: 11.10

I am trying to install ubuntu 11.10 from a bootable usb but when i boot from usb the " multiple active partitions " error show up and automatically boots in windows 7. PLEASE HELP! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

write image with *last* version of ultraiso. i had this problem with every ubuntu release. unetbootin didn't help, only the latest versions of ultraiso at the moment.