# 'multiple active partition" error while booting ubuntu from USB

Tags: 13.04, partitioning

I made my USB ubuntu bootable using " startup disk creator",but when I am trying to boot from this USB an error is coming "multiple active partition". Please help me out to solve this problem.

Steps what I did are as follows:-

Previously I had windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop, But I formatted my C drive to format both the OS, and then created ubuntu 13.04 USB bootable from my friends laptop,now I am trying to boot my laptop but error is coming "multiple active partition"

Comment: possible duplicate of [" multiple active partitions " ERROR](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69492/multiple-active-partitions-error)

Comment: Run `sudo parted -l` and edit the results into your question.

Answer (score -2):

Open gparted and deleta all partitions the make a new partition FAT/Full space of the usb flash drive, then install ubuntu again on the flash drive

Comment: What is gparted? and how to use?

Comment: GParted is a partition editor tool on linux if you dont have it the type "sudo apt-get install gparted" in the terminal open gparted and then choose you flash drive and delete all partitions on your flash drive and create a new one filesystem:fat, size= your space of your drive, then click apply

Comment: then install ubuntu